# How to identify the duplicates and move its data to other cells?

Tags: python, pandas

I have initial dataset as an excel file:

```
      Name  Number1  Number2
0     Anna      655      869
1     Anna      672       12
2     Igor      429      995
3    Alina       67      532
4    Alina       11      313
5    Alina      673      471
6   Sergey      999      942
7     Kate      332      272
8   Polina      290      776
9   Polina      193      457
10   Slava      903      673
11    Ivan      237      557
```

I need to check if the names from col `"Name"` are duplicated, then to keep the first duplicate, and to move all of the data from columns of `"Number1"` and `"Number2"` to some new created columns (based on how many the Name value has the duplicates in the dataset.

The result should be like the following:

```
      Name  Number1  Number2  Number1_2  Number2_2  Number1_3  Number2_3
0     Anna      655      869        672         12
1     Igor      429      995
2    Alina       67      532         11        313        673        471
3   Sergey      999      942
4     Kate      332      272
5   Polina      290      776        193        457
6    Slava      903      673
7     Ivan      237      557
```

My idea was to use `.drop_duplicates()` function first and to have the new spreadsheet without duplicates:

```
import pandas

filename = r"sample1.xlsx"

dataset = pandas.read_excel("sample1.xlsx")
dataframe = pandas.DataFrame(dataset)

without_duplicates = dataframe.drop_duplicates("Name")
without_duplicates.to_excel("sample1_without_duplicates.xlsx")
```

And after it to try to iterate through the other duplicates and add its data into new columns of an excel file.
So, I've created the additional columns where have checked if these are duplicates:

```
duplicates = dataframe.duplicated("Name", keep="first")
dataframe.insert(loc=0, column="isduplicate", value=duplicates)
```

So, finally I have the output of:

```
    isduplicate    Name  Number1  Number2
0         False    Anna      655      869
1          True    Anna      672       12
2         False    Igor      429      995
3         False   Alina       67      532
4          True   Alina       11      313
5          True   Alina      673      471
6         False  Sergey      999      942
7         False    Kate      332      272
8         False  Polina      290      776
9          True  Polina      193      457
10        False   Slava      903      673
11        False    Ivan      237      557
```

And have no idea of how to move the `"Number1"` and `"Number2"` values of those `"Names"` which have `True` in `"isduplicate"` column to new columns

Comment: `out = df.assign(n=df.groupby('Name').cumcount().add(1)).pivot(index='Name', columns='n').sort_index(axis=1, level=1, sort_remaining=False).pipe(lambda d: d.set_axis(d.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}'), axis=1)).reset_index()`

Comment: [How can I pivot a dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe) is a great post, yes, however, isn't it way too broad (exceptionnal so on SO) for any question to be marked as duplicate of it? Duplicate flags mean "your answer is right there", not "your answer is likely somewhere on that page that describes 20 other ways to do related yet different things". Is this discussed in the meta? Shouldn't the flagger at least indicate a line number for the exact line needed here?

Comment: @mozway curious about this flag for duplicate. Your answer seems to indicate that it is no duplicate of any line from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47152691/how-can-i-pivot-a-dataframe

Comment: @OCa yes it's broad, but we see `pivot` questions like this all the time. It's always tricky to decide whether or not to close. Some are unhappy about closing, others are unhappy about answering questions that could be duplicates. That's why I provided the command. Back to the linked duplicate, the answer is a combination of the points #10 and #11 in the Q/A.